# Understanding AMD: how to handle response flow with a one-way module relationship

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, amd

Consider, if you will, an app with a few unique views/states - let's call it a game. You have an overworld screen, a battle screen, a multiplayer interface, and maybe a minigame or two.

For the sake of argument, there isn't a lot of code in common between each view, so it lends itself well to AMD - a central controller/dispatcher, and each game state split into a separate file/view.

```
dispatcher.core.js
>   overworld.view.js
>   battle.view.js
>   tournament.view.js
>   minigame.view.js
```

Input and key commands get routed to the dispatcher, and trickle down to the current active view, which in turn manipulates the DOM as needed. One-way AMD relationships, so far so good.

The thing I'm getting hung up on is the response flow. The API response data that goes through the system is diverse, often affecting multiple views at the same time. Consider this case:

1. User presses buttons to move
2. Key commands gets routed to map view for movement animation
3. Map sends AJAX request to server for movement result
4. AJAX returns "battle commence" response to dispatcher
5. Dispatcher tells map view to disable itself, then battle view to init

The dispatcher was designed for this - to receive instruction and distribute. It seems like the obvious choice, much more than letting views affect each other directly.

However, there's a fundamental flaw here - the one-way relationship between the dispatcher and the views is violated as soon as the AJAX result is sent from the view to the dispatcher. You can either use the dispatcher for your AJAX callback, or you can instruct the dispatcher to make the AJAX call for you - but either way the view requires a way to reference the dispatcher, which as I understand it, violates the core tenet of AMD. For the life of me, I can't figure out how this would be implemented correctly!

My question is this - how would one implement such a structure correctly? Is this a limitation of AMD, or am I misunderstanding it's use on a deeper level?

---

This question is intended to be for more of the general case, but if it affects answers at all, I'm using Require and jQuery for AMD and AJAX, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a limitation of AMD, or am I misunderstanding it's use on a deeper level?

AMD does not by any means *impose* one way relationship between **object instances in general.** What it does strongly recommend to avoid (because even this is not an absolute requirement) is circular dependencies **between modules**. And the type of dependencies that matter for AMD are *loading* dependencies.

You can certainly have a module named `dispatcher` that goes:

```
define(function () {
    function Dispatcher(views) {
        this.views = views;
        for (var ix = 0, view; (view = views[ix]); ++ix)
            view.init(this);
    }

    return Dispatcher;
});
```

And `viewA`, `viewB`, that are structured like this:

```
define(function () {
    function View() {
        // ...
    }

    View.prototype.init = function (dispatcher) {
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
    };

    // Etc...

    return View;
});
```

Your main module could do:

```
define(['dispatcher', 'viewA', 'viewB'], function (Dispatcher, ViewA, ViewB) {

    var viewA = new ViewA();
    var viewB = new ViewB();

    var dispatcher = new Dispatcher([viewA, viewB]);
});
```

The above is meant to be a schematic example of what is possible, not a prescription for a good design. At any rate, the point is that is is perfectly feasible as far as AMD is concerned to have circular references between objects.

Comment: Ah, I think that's what wasn't connecting for me - it's the loading dependencies that can't be circular, not the functional references. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing about AMD that is limiting here; it's entirely about the design of your modules themselves.

---

A common way to handle this is with an [event-emitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html).

The `dispatcher` can call methods directly on a `view`, but the `view` emits events which the `dispatcher` can listen and respond to, removing the need for a circular reference (as the `view` doesn't care where the events go, so it doesn't require a reference to the `dispatcher`.)

Fitted to your example workflow, it might look like this:

1. `overworld` tracks keypress
2. `overworld` animates in response to keypress
3. `overworld` emits 'move' event for `dispatcher`

   ```
   // overworld.view
   this.emit('move', {data});

   // dispatcher
   overworld.on('move', getMoveResult) // getMoveResult fires AJAX request
   ```
4. response tells `dispatcher` it's time to battle
5. `dispatcher` updates views

   ```
   overworld.hide()
   battle.show()
   ```